# svn mkdir vs mkdir in svn

Tags: svn

I've run a command `svn mkdir file:///home/abc/workspace/svn/proj/trunk`, the thing is the trunk directory cannot be navigated when I run `cd` command. But, when I run `svn checkout file:///home/abc/workspace/svn/`, it gives the following:

```
A    svn/proj
A    svn/proj/trunk
Checked out revision
```

How do I understand this, is it `svn mkdir` different from UNIX `mkdir` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is different.

Running `svn mkdir` creates the directory in your project in the **repository**. When you checked out the project, `svn` put the new directory in your working copy.

If you ran `mkdir` alone, you would need to commit the new directory to the repository.

For reference: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.mkdir.html

Comment: So, how do I navigate to the directory run with `svn mkdir`, because I couldn't go via `cd`?

Comment: I would first create the directory with standard `mkdir`. Do your work (you can `cd` into the directory as normal), then commit your changes when done.

Comment: But, the problem is when I do that, at the time I commit, I receive an error message `svn: URL 'file:///home/abc/workspace/svn/proj' doesn't exist`. How do I resolve that?

Comment: Also, if I commit in the directory that I just created via ´normal mkdir`, I obtained an error `svn: '/home/abc/workspace/svn/proj' is not a working copy`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that you'll need to run `svn add` on the directory you created with `mkdir`. Also make sure any files or subdirectories that you want under version control are added as well.